# Using WordPress with Next.js for only certain paths

Tags: wordpress, next.js, load-balancing

I want to make a website using Next.js but I want to use WordPress for marketing pages. Let's say I want to use WordPress for a path example.com/sales and Next.js for others. I thought it could be done with load balancing but I'm new to this topic and not sure what I should do. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called incremental adoption. Basically if a certain path is not part of your nextjs app, the traffic falls back to the specified url.

[here are the official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/incremental-adoption)